# VC++ SSE code generation - is this a compiler bug?

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, x86, sse, visual-studio-debugging

A very particular code sequence in VC++ generated the following instruction (for Win32):

```
unpcklpd    xmm0,xmmword ptr [ebp-40h]
```

2 questions arise:

(1) As far as I understand the intel manual, unpcklpd accepts as 2nd argument a 128-aligned memory address. If the address is relative to a stack frame alignment cannot be forced.   Is this really a compiler bug?

(2) Exceptions are thrown from at the execution of this instruction *only when run from the debugger*, and even then not always.  Even attaching to the process and executing this code does not throw.  How can this be??

The particular exception thrown is access violation at 0xFFFFFFFF, but AFAIK that's just a code for misalignment.

---

[Edit:]
Here's some source that demonstrates the bad code generation - but typically doesn't cause a crash. (that's mostly what I'm wondering about)

[Edit 2:]
The code sample now reproduces the actual crash. This one also crashes outside the debugger - I suspect the difference occurs because the debugger launches the program at different typical base addresses.

```
    // mock.cpp
    #include <stdio.h>
    struct mockVect2d
    {
        double x, y;
        mockVect2d()    {}
        mockVect2d(double a, double b) : x(a), y(b) {}
        mockVect2d operator + (const mockVect2d& u) {
            return mockVect2d(x + u.x, y + u.y);
        }
    };

    struct MockPoly
    {
        MockPoly() {}
        mockVect2d*    m_Vrts;
        double  m_Area;
        int     m_Convex;
        bool    m_ParClear;

        void ClearPar()  { m_Area = -1.; m_Convex = 0; m_ParClear = true; }

        MockPoly(int len) { m_Vrts = new mockVect2d[len]; }

        mockVect2d& Vrt(int i) {
            if (!m_ParClear) ClearPar();
            return m_Vrts[i];
        }

        const mockVect2d& GetCenter() { return m_Vrts[0]; }
    };


    struct MockItem
    {
        MockItem() : Contour(1) {}
        MockPoly Contour;
    };

    struct Mock
    {
        Mock() {}
        MockItem m_item;
        virtual int GetCount()                  { return 2; }
        virtual mockVect2d GetCenter()  { return mockVect2d(1.0, 2.0); }
        virtual MockItem GetItem(int i) { return m_item; }
    };

    void testInner(int a)
    {
        int c = 8;
        printf("%d", c);
        Mock* pMock = new Mock;
        int Flag = true;
        int nlr = pMock->GetCount();

        if (nlr == 0)
            return;

        int flr = 1;
        if (flr == nlr)
            return;

        if (Flag)
        {
            if (flr < nlr && flr>0) {
                int c = 8;
                printf("%d", c);

                MockPoly pol(2);
                mockVect2d ctr = pMock->GetItem(0).Contour.GetCenter();

                // The mess happens here:
                //          ; 74   :            pol.Vrt(1) = ctr + mockVect2d(0., 1.0);
                // 
                //          call ? Vrt@MockPoly@@QAEAAUmockVect2d@@H@Z; MockPoly::Vrt
                //              movdqa  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR $T4[ebp]
                //              unpcklpd xmm0, QWORD PTR tv190[ebp]      **** crash!
                //              movdqu  XMMWORD PTR[eax], xmm0

                pol.Vrt(0) = ctr + mockVect2d(1.0, 0.);
                pol.Vrt(1) = ctr + mockVect2d(0., 1.0);
            }
        }
    }

    void main()
    {
        testInner(2);
        return;
    }
```

If you prefer, download a ready vcxproj with all the switches set from [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1172020/vc-bad-code-generation). This includes the complete ASM too.

Comment: x64 requires 16-byte (128-bit) stack alignment, which affects the frame alignment as well.

Comment: @Aki - thanks, but I build in Win32 (x86).

Comment: *I build in Win32* - Why did you tagged the question with `x86-64`?

Comment: There is some interesting discussion of this at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290049%28v=vs.71%29.aspx (scroll down to Stack Alignment).  Further down on the same page, there is a section for Data Alignment Exceptions and Fix-Ups.  Both sections talk about x64, x86 and Itanium.

Comment: Even if the full asm is too large, can you at least provide the function prologue? The linked bug report seems to require a login to download anything.

Comment: Which version of Visual C++ are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: this is now a [confirmed VC++ compiler bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1172020/vc-bad-code-generation), hopefully to be resolved in VS2015 RTM.

---

Edit: The connect report, like many others, is now garbage. However the compiler bug seems to be resolved in VS2017 - *not* in 2015 update 3.

Comment: Tried your sample program, and it is still crashing in VS2015 Update 3. How do you manage to get around this problem ?

Comment: As noted in a comment above - the way to work around optimizer bugs is to just jitter the code. Small changes that do not change the logic (replacing line order and such) should eventually do the trick. If reproducing to test is a long operation, just inspect the assembly output and search for the offending instruction

Comment: Thanks. Well, our source tree has millions LOC ... need to generate assembly output for all of them ...

Comment: Id say seeing it's fixed in the cpp dile where you detected it is enough

Comment: I too have encountered this bug (in production code!), and yes, jittering the code does tend to fix the issue. Dick move by MS to not back-port the fix, though.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one else has stepped up, I'm going to take a shot.

**1) If the address is relative to a stack frame alignment cannot be forced. Is this really a compiler bug?**

I'm not sure it is true that you cannot force alignment for stack variables.  Consider this code:

```
struct foo
{
    char a;
    int b;
    unsigned long long c;
};

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    foo moo;
    moo.a = 1;
    moo.b = 2;
    moo.c = 3;
}
```

Looking at the startup code for main, we see:

```
00E31AB0  push        ebp  
00E31AB1  mov         ebp,esp  
00E31AB3  sub         esp,0DCh  
00E31AB9  push        ebx  
00E31ABA  push        esi  
00E31ABB  push        edi  
00E31ABC  lea         edi,[ebp-0DCh]  
00E31AC2  mov         ecx,37h  
00E31AC7  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
00E31ACC  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
00E31ACE  mov         eax,dword ptr [___security_cookie (0E440CCh)]  
00E31AD3  xor         eax,ebp  
00E31AD5  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],eax
```

Adding __declspec(align(16)) to moo gives

```
01291AB0  push        ebx  
01291AB1  mov         ebx,esp  
01291AB3  sub         esp,8  
01291AB6  and         esp,0FFFFFFF0h  <------------------------
01291AB9  add         esp,4  
01291ABC  push        ebp  
01291ABD  mov         ebp,dword ptr [ebx+4]  
01291AC0  mov         dword ptr [esp+4],ebp  
01291AC4  mov         ebp,esp  
01291AC6  sub         esp,0E8h  
01291ACC  push        esi  
01291ACD  push        edi  
01291ACE  lea         edi,[ebp-0E8h]  
01291AD4  mov         ecx,3Ah  
01291AD9  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
01291ADE  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
01291AE0  mov         eax,dword ptr [___security_cookie (12A40CCh)]  
01291AE5  xor         eax,ebp  
01291AE7  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],eax
```

Apparently the compiler (VS2010 compiled debug for Win32), recognizing that we will need specific alignments for the code, takes steps to ensure it can provide that.

**2) Exceptions are thrown from at the execution of this instruction only when run from the debugger, and even then not always. Even attaching to the process and executing this code does not throw. How can this be??**

So, a couple of thoughts:

- "and even then not always" - Not standing over your shoulder when you run this, I can't say for certain.  However it seems plausible that just by random chance, stacks could get created with the alignment you need.  By default, x86 uses 4byte stack alignment.  If you need 16 byte alignment, you've got a 1 in 4 shot.
- As for the rest (from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290049%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#ia64alignment_topic4):

*On the x86 architecture, the operating system does not make the alignment fault visible to the application. ...you will also suffer performance degradation on the alignment fault, but it will be significantly less severe than on the Itanium, because the hardware will make the multiple accesses of memory to retrieve the unaligned data.*

TLDR: Using __declspec(align(16)) should give you the alignment you want, even for stack variables.  For unaligned accesses, the OS will catch the exception and handle it for you (at a cost of performance).

Edit1: Responding to the first 2 comments below:

Based on MS's [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx), you are correct about the alignment of stack parameters, but they propose a solution as well:

> You cannot specify alignment for function parameters. When data that
>   has an alignment attribute is passed by value on the stack, its
>   alignment is controlled by the calling convention. **If data alignment
>   is important in the called function, copy the parameter into correctly
>   aligned memory before use.**

Neither your sample on Microsoft connect nor the code about produce the same code for me (I'm only on vs2010), so I can't test this.  But given this code from your sample:

```
struct mockVect2d
{
    double x, y;
    mockVect2d(double a, double b) : x(a), y(b) {}
```

It would seem that aligning either mockVect2d or the 2 doubles might help.

Comment: Thanks, however, (1) even in your ASM sample ESP is aligned, but EBP isn't. That is, stack variables are aligned, but *stack frame* (eg arguments) isn't.  Supposedly aligning EBP  is possible too, but isn't mandated by any calling conventions, x86 compilers in practice don't do it and it doesn't help my case.  (2) As noted the current code sample crashes pretty consistently outside the debugger too.  And yes, in cases it doesn't - chance had it that the stack base was aligned.

Comment: Also from the same MSDN discussion:  'With that said, there are situations on the x86 and x64 platform where unaligned access will generate a general-protection exception. (Note that these are general-protection exceptions, not alignment-check exceptions.) This is when the misalignment occurs on a 128-bit type—specifically, SSE/SSE2-based types.'    That is the case in question - not eg assignment from a non-aligned to aligned memory buffer.

Comment: Thanks again. Aligning the parameters is not feasible for me for various reasons - but I have other workarounds (essentially perturbing the code a bit).  Anyway I was asking only for confirmation that it's a compiler bug, but that's probably as much confidence as I'd get.