# How does `sub rsp, 16` aligns the stack on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, assembly, stack, x86-64, memory-alignment

I'm currently learning x64 asm on Mac OSX using nasm.

I've come across the problem of aligning the stack, a necessary step for some system calls such as malloc, which is done with these instructions:

`push rbp
mov rbp, rsp
sub rsp, 16`

Can anyone explain me how the function prolog does align the stack ? I mean, if it's not already on a multiple of 16, why would `sub rsp, 16` correct it ?

Let's say that `esp = 0x35` , after `sub rsp, 16`, `esp = 0x25` right ? So esp wasn't aligned on a multiple of 16 before the sub, and the sub didn't align it neither so I think I haven't quite understood what "aligning the stack" means.

Can someone tell me what I should understand when I read "the stack needs to be aligned on a 16 bytes boundary" ?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't align it, as you say it just keeps alignment. Obviously the `sub rsp, 16` is only needed if you want to allocate space for 1-15 bytes of local variables. You should make sure the number there is the next multiple of 16 above the space needed, assuming the stack is already aligned. Note that the return address and the frame pointer also add up to 16 bytes, if you don't use a frame pointer you need to account for that too.

In general, the calling convention mandates that it be aligned in a particular way upon entry to all functions, so you just have to maintain that. The only place that is normally not the case is possibly at process or thread startup but that is usually taken care of by the system libraries.

Comment: Ok thanks that's what I thought, sub rsp,16 only saves up some space for local variables or functions such as malloc that requires the stack pointer to be 16 bytes further than the base pointer (at least on OSX)

Comment: While I am not on a mac, I have seen compilers do alignments for stack variables, but not using `sub`.  Some discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29176989/2189500

Comment: If the stack was aligned at function entry, then the push rbp will misalign it. As noted in the other thread, using | and rbp,-16 | will align it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that ? When the push instruction is done, stack is moved down 8 bytes (64 bits) isn't it ? Why does the sub rsp, 16 align it ? Shouldn't it be sub rsp, 8 ?